# Make a POST request using RestKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, post, restkit

I wanna make a POST request using RestKit, I work with RKObjectManager using a method postObject. The body of the request is an array of integers, JSON representation is something like [2348, 9864, 3645]. I have added a RKResponseMapping for response of service and work fine, but on service side always an array is null. What is a RKRequestMapping then I have to add? What I missing?

My code look like:

```
- (void) sendPOSTRequest:(NSArray*) postBody{
RKObjectManager *manager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:baseUrl]];

RKObjectMapping *responseMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[RKJSONArrayResponse class]];

[responseMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{ @"Code" : @"code",
                                                       @"Success":@"success",
                                                       @"Content":@"content",
                                                       @"Error": @"error"}];

RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:responseMapping
                                                                                method:RKRequestMethodPOST
                                                                           pathPattern:@"/api/Requisitions/SendReport"
                                                                               keyPath:nil
                                                                           statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];

RKObjectMapping *requestMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[NSArray class]];

RKRequestDescriptor *requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:requestMapping
                                                                               objectClass:[NSArray class]
                                                                                rootKeyPath:nil,
                                                                                    method:RKRequestMethodPOST];

[manager addRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];

[manager addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];

[self.manager postObject:postBody
                    path:@"/api/Requisitions/SendReport"
              parameters:nil
                 success:success
                 failure:failure];
}
```

---

The service code is written in C # with Web Api, here is where you will always receive the variable "report" as null.:

```
public JsonResponse<int[]> SendReport(int[] report){}
```

Comment: Where are you setting your mappings? Can you post that code? You need to set a serialization mapping for that NSArray and then route NSArrays to the key path of /send. Preferably you'd create your own class that houses the array of integers instead so you're not mapping gan NSArray itself but the class instead.

Comment: Did you create any request mapping? Show your code for it. Check what is sent with Charles (or similar tool).

Comment: This is precisely what I want to know, the correct RKRequestDescriptor instance then I should specify. I inspected the HTTP request with Wireshark, and the headers Content-Type is missing and Content-Length is zero.I would appreciate your help.

Comment: @Wain I just update a code. I have not declared a RKRequestDescriptor for NSArray.

Comment: Hi, @valheru I´ll try wrapping a NSArray of NSNumber with my own class. But, I can´t declare an instance of RKObjectMapping with NSArray and NSNumber?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 2 ways to solve this problem:

- if you want to get it done right, you need to create `RKObjectMapping` for an array of your integer values, then you need to create `RKRequestDescriptor` that will use your newly created `RKObjectMapping` and then you'll add this `RKRequestDescriptor` to your `RKObjectManager` using method `– addRequestDescriptor:`. This will make RestKit to transform an object you're passing to `postObject` method into JSON according to your `RKObjectMapping`
- I do not recommend this way. But if you just want to play around and see what you can do with minimal effort, you should pass an array of integers as `parameters` argument, like this:

  NSArray *body = @[ @1234, @7475, @4432 ];

  [manager postObject:nil path:@"/send" parameters:body ...]

Beware, that parameters argument is `NSDictionary`, but if you pass `NSArray` it'll work and will trigger a warning. 
Again, spend time to get familiar with `RKRequestDescriptor` and `RKObjectMapping`.

If you want more information on best RestKit setup and how to build maintainable app with few ObjectManagers.

Comment: I try with a second way, but don´t work for me. I know I should specify the RKRequestDescriptor, but do not know how to declare an instance of RKObjectMapping for the class NSArray.

Comment: @Joseph: RKObjectMapping* mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[NSArray class]];

Comment: Just as an FYI to anyone coming to this answer, that link is now leading to spam.

Answer (score 1):

Your desired JSON is too simple really. RestKit wants to preferably send a dictionary with a key and a value of your array of integers. The easiest thing to do in your situation is to simply use `NSJSONSerialization` directly with the array and then add the JSON to a request and use `objectRequestOperationWithRequest:success:failure:` and enqueue the operation.

Comment: I solved my problem encapsulating the array of integers into an object with two properties over to check, and declaring a RKRequestDescriptor for this class.

Comment: @Joseph could you explain how did you do that? For example you created an object with property array. How did you map it in RKRequestDescriptor?